# Remove last three dots from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to remove last three dots from the string. How it is possible?

My string is

```
Address...
```

output should be:

Address

I have tried, here is my code for remove last three characters from string..

```
str = @"Address...";              
  NSString *truncatedString = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-3];
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Comment: On the contrary, it seems to have a lot of effect - at least without further information. Could you make a small, reproducible example?

Comment: whats the value of truncatedSTring after?

Comment: You code works well. What is problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: One thing are you using string in label and its giving ... in that case your label length need to get more, rest your code is fine

Comment: I bet he got an ellipsis symbol (so he only should remove the last character instead of 3 last), but is nothing more than a long-shot guess...

Comment: May be you are using wrong value `str` instead of `truncatedString`?

Comment: values are coming from server.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine with the example provided, try printing the value and you'll see:

```
NSString *str = @"Address...";
NSLog(@"%@", str);
NSString *truncatedString = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-3];
NSLog(@"%@", truncatedString);
```

Are you sure that str has a value when you call that method?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str=@"Address...";
NSString *truncatedString = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-3];
NSLog(@"Print truncatedString=   ...%@",truncatedString);
```

This Works

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `...` with @"" directly with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`  of `NSString` and assign to same `NSString`back.

```
NSString *strAddress = @"Address...";
strAddress = [strAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"..." withString:@""];
```

Please note, it'll replace all `...` into the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
[@"LAlalla....." stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]]
```